# Prevent Cloudinary upload widget from creating folders / flatten folders

Tags: cloudinary

I'm using the [Cloudinary upload widget](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_widget) with signed uploads. When I drag a folder into the uploader, it automatically creates a folder in Cloudinary with this name (see 'foobar' folder below). Is there any way to prevent this behaviour, and just upload the files within the folder (ideally flattening all folders, including any nested ones)? I had this working before, but can't seem to get the behaviour back.

On a potentially related topic, when I drag a nested folder into the uploader, it fails with 'invalid signature' errors. Again, this was working before when it was flattening the folders.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I expected the folders to be flattened. I think this was happening before. Here's my frontend config:

```
     cloudinary.applyUploadWidget(
        document.getElementById("upload_widget_images"),
        {
          api_key: XXXXX,
          cloudName: XXXXX,
          upload_preset: XXXXX,
          sources: ["local", "dropbox"],
          uploadSignature: generateSignature,
          buttonCaption: "Upload assets",
          clientAllowedFormats: ["jpg", "jpeg", "png", "mp3", "wav"],
          styles: uploaderStyles,
          button_class: "uploader-button",
          max_files: 2000,
          // Downscale the image to 800px width / 500 height
          maxImageWidth: 800,
          maxImageHeight: 500,
          folder: "myfolder", // have tried with and without this
          use_filename: true, // have tried with and without this
          useAssetFolderAsPublicIdPrefix: false, // have tried with and without this
        }, 
        (error, result) => {}
      );
```

and the backend code:

```
     const signature = cloudinary.utils.api_sign_request(
        params_to_sign,
        process.env.CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET
      );
```

It seems that when multiple folders / a nested folder are dragged into the uploader, the `params_to_sign` becomes an array, so no wonder the signing isn't working.

[image: terminal output]

Comment: The upload widget has the `pre-Batch` validation feature where you can analyze and get the [folder structure for the source file](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_widget#pre_batch_validation). And using the information, you can update the `folder` parameter to where your files will be uploaded in your Media Library account [through the `prepareUploadParams` event](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_widget#prepare_upload_parameters). In the same event, the signature can be calculated as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, thanks to @epasos_573 at Cloudinary support, I have the answer. You need to pre-batch with prepareUploadParams. Here's what my final upload code looks like:

```
 cloudinary.applyUploadWidget(
    document.getElementById("upload_widget"),
    {
      api_key: "XXXXXXXX",
      cloudName: "XXXXXXX",
      upload_preset: "XXXXXX",
      sources: ["local", "dropbox"],
      buttonCaption: "Upload images",
      clientAllowedFormats: ["jpg", "jpeg", "png", "tiff", "tif", "gif"],
      prepareUploadParams: (callback, params) => {
        params = [].concat(params); //params can be a single object or an array of objects
        Promise.all(
          params.map((req) =>
            // getSignature is my own func that calls the backend to create the signature
            getSignature(req).then((response) =>
              Object.assign(
                {
                  signature: response.signature,
                  apiKey: "XXXXXXXXXX",
                },
                response.upload_params
              )
            )
          )
        ).then((results) => callback(results.length === 1 ? results[0] : results));
      },
      styles: uploaderStyles,
      button_class: "uploader-button",
      max_files: 2000,
      maxImageWidth: 800,
      maxImageHeight: 500,
      assetFolder: "XXXXXXX",
      folder: "XXXXXXXX",
    },
    (error, result) => {
      if (result.event === "queues-end") {
        // Do things
      }
    }
  );
```